# Hovering a tag when viewing a suggested edit directly from the question page shows the tag popup behind the edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, suggested-edits, popups

When viewing a suggested edit directly on a question page, it pops up a white box with the suggested edit. However, when you hover over a tag for its description, the popup box produced appears *behind* the white box containing the suggested edit. At first, I thought it just didn't work for suggested edits, but then I noticed that the black box sticks out partially below the edit's window.

[image: See the freehand circle]

Comment: gah, you just *had* to notice the shadow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch. Z-index updated; bug fixed.